# NSRunLoop cancelPerformSelectorsWithTarget's not working

Tags: ios, nsrunloop

I have this following code and I am not getting the results I expected.

```
#import "CancelPerformSelectorTestAppDelegate.h"
@implementation CancelPerformSelectorTestAppDelegate
@synthesize window;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        NSTimeInterval waitThisLong = i;
        [self performSelector:@selector(foo) withObject:nil afterDelay: waitThisLong];
    }

    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] cancelPerformSelectorsWithTarget: self];

    return YES;
}

- (void) foo {
    static unsigned int timesCalled = 0;
    ++timesCalled;
    NSLog(@"%s: I am called for the %d-st/nd/th time", __func__, timesCalled);
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {}
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {}
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {}
- (void)applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:(UIApplication *)application {}
- (void)dealloc {
    [window release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

I expected the function to be called about 0 times, perhaps 1 if the CPU is having a slow day.

The function will execute 10 times! :( Always. What am I doing wrong, and how could I achieve the results I expected?

Thanks in advance, a lot, 
Nick

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to cancel the request using the [NSObject](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class method +cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:

For example,

```
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
```

There's an example in the "handling tap gestures" section of the [Event Handling Guide for multitouch events](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/MultitouchEvents/MultitouchEvents.html)

Answer (score 1):

You want this:

```
[UIApplication cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
```

Comment: This works too, because `UIApplication` inherits the method from `NSObject`