# `cancelPerformSelectorsWithTarget:` vs `cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:`

Tags: cocoa-touch, foundation, nsrunloop, performselector

I am building a kind of simulation with ever-smaller intervals between "ticks":

```
- (void) simulationTick {
    if (self.currentTick >= kNumberOfSimulationTicks)
        return; // recursion anchor

    // ... do stuff ...

    self.currentTick = self.currentTick + 1;
    [self performSelector:@selector(simulationTick) withObject:nil
               afterDelay:2.5 * pow(0.95,(double)self.currentTick)]; // acceleration
}
```

When leaving the Simulation screen, I want to stop the simulation, so I do this with

```
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self]
```

I first tried using

```
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] cancelPerformSelectorsWithTarget:self]
```

… but this didn’t work.

**Why not?**

Apparently there are [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830383/nsrunloop-cancelperformselectorswithtargets-not-working) [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971195/iphone-cancelperformselectorwithtarget-not-working) who had the same problem and the same solution. But nowhere could I find exactly *why*. What’s the difference between the two?